# Extracting link from a website using python, scrapy is not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape website link from "https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/bayside-bowl-portland-me-1031451", and I have used proper code of xpath i.e. `response.xpath("//a[@title='website']/@href").get()`, but it shows null result while scraping.

Comment: Can you try with [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)? It's much easier.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to scrape from the page exactly? What do you mean when you say "website link"?

Comment: I don't think what you are searching for exists? The only titles on that site are facebook, twitter and instagram, no "website".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some websites (in fact, **many**) use Javascript to generate content. That's why you need always check a source HTML code.

For this page you'll find that all information you need is inside a `script` tag with this text `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =` . You need to get this text and next you can use `json` module to parse it:

```
import scrapy
import json

class TheknotSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'theknot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/bayside-bowl-portland-me-1031451']

    def parse(self, response):
        initial_state_raw = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ")]/text()').re_first(r'window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = (\{.+?)$')
        # with open('Samples/TheKnot.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write(initial_state_raw)
        initial_state = json.loads(initial_state_raw)
        website = initial_state['vendor']['vendor']['displayWebsiteUrl']
        print(website)
```